# VTOL Aircraft Take-Off Mechanics Question

Tags: cfd

These question(s) could be potentially trivial, but its difficult to find visuals on CFD of VTOL aircraft. While watching a video of the f-35 performing its vertical take-off/hovering, I noticed the horizontal stabilizers, as well as the flaps being deployed down. Does this happen as a means to "scoop" as much air as possible, to help further push/lif the aircraft up?
I'm also curious what the overall affect of airfoils on VTOL aircraft such as the harrier/f-35. Do airfoils affect hovering performance or only horizontal transition/flight?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

Yes as you guess the flaps and stabilizer being down are to take advantage of the ground effect and scoop more air deflected by the ground at take off and also as you guessed again they help smooth transition into horizontal flight.

When the engines gradually rotate back to horizontal configuration, directing the thrust vector back the flaps and horizontal stabilizers angled down helps with additional lift and redundant authority of the controls. When enough lift from the wings and empennage is produced the flaps and stabilizers are retrieved.

So there is a softer and safer transition. Especially under the combat conditions where the pilot may lack perfect visual ques. However the VT is not an official part of the F-35's maneuvers. VL is.

I like you am an avid aviation hobbyist and currently fly a Cessna 172, but decades ago I did aerobatics and hang gliding.

Her is a rendering buy Computer Fluid Design software. [image: CFD rendering]

Comment: Kamran, than you for the response. That helped clear up several questions I had. The picture is awesome, I had so much trouble finding that. One other question, when an f-35/harrier is in hover and it decides to yaw or slightly move horizontally, is there any input from control surfaces or pure Thrust vectoring?

Comment: @JohnA, I guess its purely thrust vectoring. Remember the controls are basically wings and the are useless until they move fast enough to create lift.

Comment: thank you for taking the time to answer some of my questions. Very much appreciated!